# Display file contents with evaluated variables

Tags: shell, unix

Let's say I have a template text file most of whose content is static but has some variables.  E.g.

```
My favorite site is ${FAV_SITE}
```

Let's say that FAV_SITE is set to stackoverflow.com:

```
export FAV_SITE=stackoverflow.com
```

How do I print to STDOUT the contents of the file with the vars resolved, i.e.

```
My favorite site is stackoverflow.com
```

without using fancy tools like sed or awk?

Comment: I think you'll need to use fancy tools like Perl or Python.  Using `awk` might be OK; using `sed` only works if your list of environment variables is quite small.

Comment: OK.  I am a proficient Perl user, awk not so much.  How would I do it in awk?

Comment: In a POSIX-compliant version of `awk`, the associative array `ENVIRON` contains the environment variables indexed by variable name.  So, the basic information is available; it's just a nuisance working out how to the substitution with the `gsub()` function.

Comment: wow `sed` and `awk` are considered fancy?

Comment: they are not that fancy, it is just that i would expect there would be a simpler utility command to resolve a template file with env vars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $inFile = $ARGV[0];

print "\nInput File=".$inFile;

open(FILEHANDLE, "<$inFile") || die("Could not open file");

my @fileLines = <FILEHANDLE>;

my $rslt;

foreach my $line(@fileLines)
{
    #chomp($line);

    #print "\nLINE BEFORE=".$line;

    while($line =~ m/(\${\w+})/g)
    {
        if($1)
        {
            my $plchldr = $1;

            my $varName = $plchldr;

            $varName =~ s/(\$|{|})//g;

            my $varVal = $ENV{$varName};

            if($varVal)
            {
                $line =~ s/\Q$plchldr/$varVal/g;
            }
        }
    }

    $rslt .= $line;

    #print "\nLINE AFTER=".$line;
}

print "\nRESULT = ".$rslt;

close(FILEHANDLE);

print "\n";

exit(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an almost trivial bit of Perl that does the job.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#
# Substitute environment variables into text

use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>)
{
    while (m/\${(\w+)}/g)
    {
        my $env = $1;
        if (defined $ENV{$env})
        {
            my $sub = $ENV{$env};
            s/\${$env}/$sub/g;
        }
    }
    print;
}
```

If the environment variable is not defined, it leaves the `${VARIABLE}` notation unchanged.

For example, on the input data:

```
This is ${HOME} and so is this (${HOME}) and that's ${USER} and that's all.
This is ${UNDEFINED} and that is ${UNDEF} too.
```

the output might be:

```
This is /work4/jleffler and so is this (/work4/jleffler) and that's jleffler and that's all.
This is ${UNDEFINED} and that is ${UNDEF} too.
```

The Perl probably isn't as compact is it could be, but it is more or less comprehensible if you know that the read operator `<>` and the match, substitute and print operators work on the default variable, `$_`.

---

Using Perl 5.12.1 (home-built) on RHEL 5 Linux (don't ask), I used:

```
$ cat x3 
This is ${UNDEFINED} and that is ${UNDEF} too.
This is ${HOME} and so is this (${HOME}) and that's ${USER} and that's all.
$ perl subenv.pl x3
This is ${UNDEFINED} and that is ${UNDEF} too.
This is /work4/jleffler and so is this (/work4/jleffler) and that's jleffler and that's all.
$
```

Just be careful if you create the template with a here document; the shell will expand those variables too.

I also found Perl 5.8.8 in `/usr/bin/perl` on the RHEL machine and that produced the same output.  I also checked Perl 5.16.0 on Mac OS X 10.7.5, with the corresponding result (different home directory).  I also found a Perl 5.6.1 on a HP-UX 11.00 machine where `${USER}` was not set in the environment, but it substituted `${HOME}` correctly.

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work.  it looks like it never enters into the nested while loop and just prints the file content with the variables unresolved

Comment: Really?  Which version of Perl are you using?

Comment: the way i ran it was subEnvVar.pl template.tpl where i dumped your code into subEnvVar.pl

Comment: The biggest drawback of this type of solution is that it does not handle expressions like `${FOO:-bar}`

Comment: @WilliamPursell: This code doesn't; it could be made to do so, but then again, how complex is the template going to be?  And, against that, it doesn't run into issues with accidentally executing shell script with back-quotes etc. If the `${VAR:-value}` stuff is reasonably straight-forward (strings, possibly single quoted or  double quoted), then a more complex regex could deal with the notation.  But if you get into the full panoply of possible Bash syntaxes, including indirect variable expansion, then it is messy in Perl.

Answer (score 1):

Can you make the template file a bash script?

```
#!/bin/bash
# This is a template, execute it to get interpolated text:
cat <<HERE
My favorite site is ${FAV_SITE}
HERE
```

Example of use:

```
export FAV_SITE=stackoverflow.com
bash ./template.txt.sh
```

<strike>(oh and you might need to visit reddit.com)</strike>

Comment: why do you say i need to go on reddit.com?

Comment: Only way to explain the exported value for `FAV_SITE`, really :) (_joke_)

Answer (score 0):

Always be wary of `eval`, but:

```
while read l; do eval echo "\"$l\""; done < input-file
```

Only use this if you control the input.  For example, if the input contains
a line like `"; rm -rf /"` it would be most unfortunate to run this script.